# how to make a function() enable/disable using switch widget in android studio?

Tags: java, android

I got a function called updateTv() in my program which will run as soon as the app is opened. Now what I want is to create a button which will enable and disable the function updateTv(), so when the app is opened, the function updateTv() should run only when the switch is on/enable and when the switch is off, it should be disabled.

Here is my code:

```
final Runnable updater = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        updateTv();
        push(mEMA);

    }

};
```

after few suggestions, I tried this,

```
final Runnable updater = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            aSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        {updateTv();
                            push(mEMA);
                        }
                        aSwitch.setText("disable");
                    } else {
                        aSwitch.setText("enable");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
```

still there's a problem, whenever it is switched on, its runs only once

Comment: Your problem here is when you run it once you directly change the value to disable aSwitch.setText("disable");

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using SharedPreference in your project.
Suppose you have Enabled and Disabled button in the layout, when you click on Enabled you will store boolean in your shared preference with value as true,

Now when you start your application you will get the value from sharedpreference about Enabled/Disabled and move ahead with your code.

```
final Runnable updater = new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
              if(isEnabled){
                updateTv();
                push(mEMA);
              }
            }


        };
```

Comment: while using if(isEnabled) im getting an error. I still cant find a solution. can you explain more elaborately?

Comment: if i answer your question and it helps you to achieve your goal then please accept it.

Comment: yeah thanks. above in the question i have edited with the updated code. now the problem is, i have to switch it on and off each time to run it, but what i want is to once i switch i on, it should start running continuously

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;

public class test {

    public static volatile boolean activated = false;

    public test() {

         JFrame q = new JFrame();
         q.setLayout(null);
         q.setSize(400, 400);
         q.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
         q.setTitle("Tv something?");

         JRadioButton button = new JRadioButton("on/off");
         button.setSize(100, 40);
         button.setLocation(q.getWidth()/2 - button.getWidth()/2, q.getHeight()/2 - button.getHeight()/2);
         button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (button.isSelected()) {
                    activated = true;
                } else {
                    activated = false; 
                }
            }
         });
         q.add(button);

         q.setVisible(true);

    }


}
```

now take that (volatile) boolean and put it inside your runnable like Silvans Solanki suggested like this:

```
final Runnable updater = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
          if(activated){
            updateTv();
            push(mEMA);
          }
        }


    };
```

edit:

for android u can do something like this:

```
Button btn= new Button(this);  
btn.settext("Submit");  
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()   
{
    public void onClick(View view) 
     {
           activated = !activated;
       }
});
```